# API Routes with more than one parameter in Joomla 4/5

Tags: joomla-4.x, joomla-api, joomla-5.x

I have an API route that should accept more than one parameter, but it seems that only one parameter is being recognised, like this:

```
new Route(
  ['POST'],
  'v1/myapiendpoint/:nr/:id',
  'mycomponent.mycontrolerfunction',
  ['nr' => '(\d+)', 'id' => '(\d+)' ],  // more than one parameter not recognized?!
  [
     'component' => 'com_mycomponent',
     'public'    => false
  ]
)
```

How can I define routes with more than one parameter? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in router documentation. Capture group brackets are actually added automatically. So you shouldn't use them in your patterns:

```
['nr' => '\d+', 'id' => '\d+']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. It works.